# Override default relational methods in loopback

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I need to override a default method in loopback, I 've tried the basic ones like

```
Customer.find(), Customer.deleteById()
```

But I want to edit realtional method, like

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/customers/{customerId}/orders
```

Where I need to get some extra details just not the orders placed by that customer.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more information about what are you exactly trying to achieve? There are several ways you could go. You can certainly override methods (on a model level or an endpoint level), but you could also just create hooks ([remote](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html) or [operation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html)) and add whatever extra details you find necessary. You could also set a [default scope](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html) if these extra details come from related models.

Comment: [link] (http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/customers/{customerId}/orders)

this is an auto-generated API by loopback.

When I hit this API, the results which I get back are orders which have that particular ID {customerId}.

What I want is when I hit that API, I want to execute another custom function i.e check in other collection (guest) with that {customerId} and return that orders as well with that {customerId} .